# Invalid ELF image for this architecture

Tags: qemu, emulation

I'm trying to load a Busybox binary with qemu-ppc-static with this command:

> sudo chroot . ./qemu-ppc-static ./bin/busybox

And I get this error:

> /lib/ld.so.1: Invalid ELF image for this architecture

lib/ld.so.1 is in the chrooted directory but it looks like it's trying to load another ld.so.1

file busybox:

> bin/busybox: ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.3, stripped

Comment: And what does file lib/ld.so.1 say?

Answer (score 2):

You get this error message because the ELF is stripped. See [qemu-vs-strip](http://www.devttys0.com/2011/12/qemu-vs-sstrip/) for more information.

This problem is fixed in the latest QEMU, so you have to update your QEMU or compile the latest from source.

Comment: I did compile the latest version: qemu-ppc version 2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
But now I get this error with this command: `sudo chroot . ./qemu-ppc ./bin/busybox`
`chroot: failed to run command ‘./qemu-ppc’: No such file or directory`

Comment: qemu-ppc is in the chroot directory